# Finding Green's Function for Particular Case

Tags: greens-function

Determine the Green's Function for the particular case of the set $D=\{(x_1,x_2)\in R^2 : x_2 < -3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of calculating Green's function for $ x_2 > 0 $ in the following [handout from a university course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/greensfcns.pdf). What you are asking is a simple modification of that case.