# Existence of pathological continuous map $[0,1]\to[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a continuous map $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ from the unit interval to itself such that the preimages $f^{-1}(t)$ are infinite for every point $0\le t\le 1$?

Comment: Take the projection to the first coordinate, of the [Peano curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve) from $[0,1]$ filling the square $[0,1]^2$. For each $t\in[0,1]$ there is a pre-image $x_r\in[0,1]$ for each point $(t,r)\in[0,1]^2$, where $x_r$ is a time at which the Peano curve passes through $(t,r)$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy This is worth to be an offcial answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost Stick to closing questions [perfectly](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3506874/736212) [good](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3506929/736212) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3506947/736212). I will stick to doing math and posting answers wherever I want. I don't need you to tell me how worthy my answers are. It is there such that the answer gets to the person who asked, independently of the human sacrifices that sometimes, and sometimes not, people like you like to try to enforce in this website.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I appreciate your friendly response.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy this is worth to be an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes such functions do exist. For an example consider a space filling curve $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ and compose with the projection on the first coordinate.

Note that in this case the fibers all have cardinality $\mathfrak c$. It is also possible, [though harder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599921/countable-infinity-to-one-function/1600271#1600271) to have countable fibers. However for $\aleph_0<\kappa<\mathfrak c$ there is no continuous map $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with fibers of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: I was going to post only the first part as a community wiki after seeing the comments, but I realized I had something more which could be interesting to say and went for a normal answer

Comment: The final comment is a consequence of the fact that the fibres are Borel sets (or compact Hausdorff), of course. Not even a single fibre can ever have such a size.